# Java not providing expected result for a expression

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I'm trying to implement the following expression s=ut+½at² but it does not give an expected result for `u = 2, a = 2, t = 1 => s = 3.00 m`

I've tried moving around the parentheses/brackets but it does not fix the problem...

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise4 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        float speed, time, acceleration, distance;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the initial speed: ");
        speed = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("Please enter the acceleration: ");
        time = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("Please enter the time spent traveling: ");
        acceleration = input.nextFloat();
        distance = (speed * time) + (((0.5 f * acceleration) * time) * time);
        System.out.println("The object traveled a distance of " + String.format("%.2f", distance) + " metres");
    }
}
```

Other expected results that do work are :

```
u = 0, a = 0, t = 0 => s0 .00 m
u = 0, a = 1, t = 1 => s0 .50 m
u = 1, a = 1, t = 1 => s1 .50 m
```

Comment: "it does not give an expected result", so, probably, your code is wrong. what is the input you provide, what is the output you expect and what do you get?
Have you debugged your code?

Comment: Aside: don't do calculation with `float`s. Use `double`.

Comment: @AndyTurner why

Comment: You save acceleration in `time` variable and time in `acceleration` variable.

Comment: @Michael because of all the precision you lose.

Comment: @AndyTurner Who are you to say what precision is required? The float datatype exists for a reason.

Comment: @Michael the `short` datatype exists for a reason too, and I don't remember the last time I read code that used that. And who am I? A sign, not a cop.

Comment: @AndyTurner then apparently you never needed `short`. If you wanna see a usage of it check this class `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBuffer` which is one really used class. The datatypes exists to be used. The reason and The place is decided from the developer and the business.

Answer (score 3):

You have messed up the order of your inputs.
You are asking for the value of acceleration, but assigning that input to `time` variable.

```
System.out.print("Please enter the acceleration: ");
        time = input.nextFloat();
```

Just change the order and it would work just fine.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise4 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        float speed, time, acceleration, distance;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the initial speed: ");
        speed = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("Please enter the acceleration: ");
        acceleration = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("Please enter the time spent traveling: ");
        time = input.nextFloat();
        distance = (speed * time) + (((0.5f * acceleration) * time) * time);
        System.out.println("The object traveled a distance of " + String.format("%.2f", distance) + " metres"); 
    }
}
```